# boolean modifier for 1 cylinder inside another cylinder

Tags: modifiers

I cannot get the boolean difference modifier to work for these 2 cylinders as shown. What am I doing wrong? The normals on both cylinders are point outwards

[image]

Comment: have you tried to hide it or delete the boolean object after applying?

Comment: Try changing from *'Exact'* to *'Fast'*

Comment: @moonboots: I will check the next time. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing works just fine.  You can't see that it works because the Boolean modifier is non-destructive.  Cylinder.001 still exists.

You can do one of several things, including but not limited to:

1. Hide Cylinder.001 by clicking the eye icon in the outliner, or selecting it and typing <kbd>H</kbd> in the 3d Viewport resulting in the eye looking closed;

[image: Outliner showing Cylinder.001 hidden]

2. Placing it in a different collection and hiding that collection;
3. Applying the modifier and deleting Cylinder.001; or
4. Changing its Viewport Display property to *Bounds* or *Wire* so that you can see that it still exists, but also see the Boolean effect.

[image: Object properties showing Viewport Display dropdown.]

Your choice depends on your workflow.  A very popular workflow is to

- Create a separate collection called something like *Cutters* and move it to that collection
- Change its Viewport Display to wire or bounds.

This gives you the flexibility of hiding all of the cutters you are using, or only a few of them, while still allowing you to see both the result of the Boolean and why that result occurred.  Here's an example:

[image: Cylinder.001 moved to cutters collection]

[image: Cylinder.001 displayed as wire]

The 3D Viewport:

[image: The 3D Viewport that results]

Comment: I like the idea of creating cutters. Works perfect for me! THanks alot!